# Accessing session variable inside magento files

Tags: php, magento, session

I have a custom file in which I am using sessions to store the variables  and I need to access those variables in the magento files.
my Custom folder structure
magento/custom/checkmail.php
I need to access session variables in the magento file i.e.
magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
I have started the session in magento file login.phtml. But the values are not passing to it .its passing "null" value. How would I go with it.

Answer (score 0):

how are you saving the value in session 
try this

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
$session->setData("custom_field", 'custom value');
$yourValue = $session->getData("custom_field");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but how to access this session inside magento file

Answer (score 0):

In your `checkmail` write like this

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
        // set data in session start //
        $session->setData("orderid", $data['orderid']);
```

and in `login.phtml` get the value like this

```
// Getting values from session which was set during url checking
    $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
    $relatedOrder = $session->getData("orderid");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Its passing "null" value again

Comment: paste your code here.. before setting data check if your data has any value assigned..

Comment: checkmail.php
?php
session_start();
$email=$_GET['f'];
$ext=$_GET['ext'];
$to_mail= $email.$ext;
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
// set data in session start //
$session->setData("mailid", $to_mail);
$yourValue=$session->getData("mailid");
var_dump($yourValue);
?>

Comment: login.phtml
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
session_start();
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
$relatedOrder = $session->getData("mailid");
var_dump($relatedOrder);
?>

Comment: Yes checked it. value is assigned to the session variable

Comment: are you crazy??...why session_start() ??  you dont have to write this...remove that . And why require_once("app/Mage.php"); this??  why you are adding app/mage...login.phtml is already running after adding app/mage from index.php

Comment: paste your checkmail.php here..you need to include app/mage here. Because its not a magento file.

Comment: ok.I have removed it.values are assigned to session variables in checkmail.php but those values are not passing to login.phtml.

Comment: <?php require_once("app/Mage.php");
session_start();
$email=$_GET['f'];
$ext=$_GET['ext'];
$to_mail= $email.$ext;
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
// set data in session start //
$session->setData("mailid", $to_mail);
$yourValue=$session->getData("mailid");
var_dump($yourValue);
?>

Comment: paste you login page here..if you dont show us your code how could we identify?

Comment: $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",array("name"=>"frontend")); $relatedOrder = $session->getData("mailid");     just add this..